# How to get Nan values for certain values in array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am generating some random numbers and I am try to apply a condition that if values > 80 , then put None, but I am unable to get the results. My code is as follow

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from numpy import random

total = 200 
rand_numbers = np.random.randint(0, 100, total)
corrupt_values = np.random.randint(0, 100, total) > 80
flag = False
if flag:
    rand_numbers = [v for flag, v in zip(corrupt_values, rand_numbers)]
else:
   rand_numbers = None
print 'rand_numbers: ', rand_numbers
```

I am trying to get results like

```
rand_numbers [20, 50, Nan, Nan, 40, 10] so that values greater than 80 are replaced by Nan
```

I am try to generate 200 random numbers in rand_numbers and then I am making a condition that if values exceeded than 80, then it will put NaN instead of values otherwise value. I am trying to zip these two arrays and making that condition to work, but I am struggling with it. I am new to coding. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need first cast values to `float` (because `NaN` is `float`) and then change values by condition:

```
np.random.seed(100)
total = 100 
rand_numbers = np.random.randint(0, 100, total)
corrupt_values = rand_numbers > 80
print (rand_numbers)
[ 8 24 67 87 79 48 10 94 52 98 53 66 98 14 34 24 15 60 58 16  9 93 86  2 27
  4 31  1 13 83  4 91 59 67  7 49 47 65 61 14 55 71 80  2 94 19 98 63 53 27
 56 30 48 47 39 38 44 18 64 56 34 53 74 17 72 13 30 17 53 68 50 91 91 83 53
 78  0 13 57 76  3 70  3 84 79 10 87 60  3 48 52 43 36  5 71 38 86 94 98 42]

print (corrupt_values)
[False False False  True False False False  True False  True False False
  True False False False False False False False False  True  True False
 False False False False False  True False  True False False False False
 False False False False False False False False  True False  True False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False  True
  True  True False False False False False False False False False  True
 False False  True False False False False False False False False False
  True  True  True False]

rand_numbers = rand_numbers.astype(float)
rand_numbers[corrupt_values] = None
print (rand_numbers)
[  8.  24.  67.  nan  79.  48.  10.  nan  52.  nan  53.  66.  nan  14.  34.
  24.  15.  60.  58.  16.   9.  nan  nan   2.  27.   4.  31.   1.  13.  nan
   4.  nan  59.  67.   7.  49.  47.  65.  61.  14.  55.  71.  80.   2.  nan
  19.  nan  63.  53.  27.  56.  30.  48.  47.  39.  38.  44.  18.  64.  56.
  34.  53.  74.  17.  72.  13.  30.  17.  53.  68.  50.  nan  nan  nan  53.
  78.   0.  13.  57.  76.   3.  70.   3.  nan  79.  10.  nan  60.   3.  48.
  52.  43.  36.   5.  71.  38.  nan  nan  nan  42.]
```

Similar solution (from deleted answer) with [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
rand_numbers = rand_numbers.astype(float)
rand_numbers = np.where(corrupt_values, np.nan, rand_numbers)
print (rand_numbers)
[  8.  24.  67.  nan  79.  48.  10.  nan  52.  nan  53.  66.  nan  14.  34.
  24.  15.  60.  58.  16.   9.  nan  nan   2.  27.   4.  31.   1.  13.  nan
   4.  nan  59.  67.   7.  49.  47.  65.  61.  14.  55.  71.  80.   2.  nan
  19.  nan  63.  53.  27.  56.  30.  48.  47.  39.  38.  44.  18.  64.  56.
  34.  53.  74.  17.  72.  13.  30.  17.  53.  68.  50.  nan  nan  nan  53.
  78.   0.  13.  57.  76.   3.  70.   3.  nan  79.  10.  nan  60.   3.  48.
  52.  43.  36.   5.  71.  38.  nan  nan  nan  42.]
```

Comment: I am generating two arrays. one for random values and other for true, false array. and then I want to impose the condition that if the value is greater than 80, then put NaN.

Comment: I want to zip those two arrays

Comment: Hmm, do you need `rand_numbers[corrupt_values] = np.nan` ?

Comment: yes something like this rand_numbers[corrupt_values]. because I had multiple columns. and I will generate random values for each column and then will pose NaN when values > 80

Comment: but if you observe, it is also taking into account values > 80 and not putting NaN for them

Comment: Yes, because it is different array. So need `rand_numbers[rand_numbers > 80] = None`, right?

Comment: these are 2 different arrays, thats why i want to zip them and then take this action on those arrays. that if value > 80 then put NaN otherwise not

Comment: It seems I understand. Problem is `np.random.randint(0, 100, total)` return another array, so no match. Instead need `corrupt_values = rand_numbers > 80`

Comment: still get values greater than 80, i guess the problem lies in zipping properly. and the corrupt values are generated like  . 'corrupt_values = np.random.randint(0, 100, total) > 80'.............if you print rand_numbers several times, you will see values > 80

Comment: Ok, if have `rand_numbers = np.array([10,50,80,100])` and 
`corrupt_values = np.array([100,50,20,10]) > 80` the what is desired output?

Comment: @corrupt_values is the array of true and false only. maybe I am missing something to understand which is very basic.

Comment: Yes, in my sample too. `corrupt_values = np.array([100,50,20,10]) > 80`

Comment: So need `rand_numbers = rand_numbers.astype(float)` and 
`rand_numbers[corrupt_values] = None`

Comment: or `rand_numbers = rand_numbers.astype(float)`
`rand_numbers[rand_numbers > 80] = None` ?

Comment: I understand my confusion. I accept your answer because it works fine. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

you can use list comprehension

```
import numpy as np

total = 200 
rand_numbers = np.random.randint(0, 100, total)

result=[i if i<=80 else float('NaN') for i in rand_numbers]
```

that will give you :

```
 >>> result
[64, 23, 12, 8, 70, nan, 13, 19, 73, 18, 78, 25, 77, 45, nan, 6, 15, nan, nan, 47, nan, 39, 5, 9, 22, 59, 57, 71, 8, 24, 76, 33, 66, nan, 21, 39, 48, 23, 40, nan, nan, 75, 68, 17, 52, nan, 71, 55, 10, 53, 51, 21, 35, 6, 67, 10, 34, nan, 24, 11, 42, 72, 74, 40, 63, 8, 57, 10, nan, 45, nan, 18, nan, 80, 6, 21, 22, 2, 51, 54, 80, 50, 63, 40, nan, 26, 43, 65, 7, 13, 54, 69, 12, nan, nan, 40, 44, nan, 78, 45, 55, 72, 6, 46, 43, 33, 24, 69, 77, 51, 52, 51, nan, 32, 22, 54, 53, 25, 61, 32, 8, nan, 75, 9, 22, nan, nan, 54, 32, 49, nan, 8, 59, 44, 14, 62, 61, 37, 60, 56, 12, 23, 50, 76, 5, 14, 46, nan, 58, 18, 53, 18, 39, 10, 1, 17, 36, 31, 42, 71, 61, 39, 27, 79, nan, 44, 76, nan, 26, 3, 26, 19, 64, 6, 41, 65, 76, 31, nan, 12, nan, 77, 8, 49, nan, nan, nan, 5, 40, 15, nan, 42, 14, 12, 75, 54, 47, 65, 9, 12]
```

**EDIT**

It's also possible :

```
import numpy as np

total = 200 
rand_numbers = np.random.randint(0, 100, total)
corrupt_values = rand_numbers > 80

result=[i[0] if i[1]==False else float('nan') for i in zip(rand_numbers, corrupt_values)]
```

Comment: its working but I want to zip those 2 arrays and trying to implement the condition that if values > 80 then put NaN otherwise values

Comment: see Edit in my post

Comment: Thanks a lot. it also works fine.  and jezrael solution also fulfil the requirements.